# Jackson serialize null or empty object

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

There is a POJO:

```
class A {
   private B b;
}
```

where B:

```
class B {
   private String c;
}
```

Is there a proper way of making Jackson serialize object of `A`, having `A.b = null`(or even `b` having all of it's fields as empty or default) in a form of:

```
{
   b: {}
}
```

And without the use of custom serializers. The upper POJO is actually complex, and maintaining the serializer will bring more trouble than benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set default property inclusionto to `Include.NON_NULL`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new A()));
  }
}

class A {
  private B b = new B();

  public B getB() {
    return b;
  }

  public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }
}

class B {
  private String c;

  public String getC() {
    return c;
  }

  public void setC(String c) {
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "b" : { }
}
```

Comment: It would appear so, but once I apply NON_NULL, the "b" isn't shown at all (null case)

Comment: So, you need `{"b": {}}` even if `A.b=null`? In that case you need to write custom serialiser. In case you have many `POJO` classes you can write generic serialiser for them.

Comment: Yes, generally it turned out this way. Thanks for your help